# RN4020 data communication without MLDP

Tags: bluetooth

I want to transfer data from my Smartphone to the RN4020 Bluetooth module. The easiest way is to use MLDP service. But I don't want to use it as CMD/MLDP pin is connected to +3.3V.
And the only way to exit from the MLDP mode is power off/on.

That's why I'm looking for another way. 
It should be possible to create private service for that. But I don't know is it necessary to update/create the firmware for the private service?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This question appears to boil down to "how do I transfer data from a smartphone to a bluetooth module" and, I'm not sure it sits comfortably in EE.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to do that now.
I used the examples from the 
RN4020 Bluetooth Low Energy Module User’s Guide.

I didn't found the Android APP mentioned there. 
Instead I used the "nRF Master Control Panel" APP and it is working.